# Requests to load balancer aren't geographically routed to nearest region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have this setup:

- An Exernal Global Load Balancer

---

- 1 Backend Services, with these backends:
- Backend 1 in us-central1, a cloud run serverless neg
- Backend 2 in us-east1, a cloud run serverless neg
- Backend 3 in me-central1, a cloud run serverless neg

---

- Routing rules are the default(simple path and host rule)
- No session affinity
- Balancing Policy: Least Request
- No CDN

Now being in Jordan, when I send a requst, I see it going to us-east1 service, despite me-central1 being the closest to me. And I don't see any errors or bad metrics on console.

So why is this happening?

Comment: Distance is not the determining factor. The lowest latency is. That means a location that is geographically closer might actually be the longer path. Africa and the Middle East have challenges regarding networking. Edit your post to show how you have configured the load balancer, backends, and URL map to verify a correct load balancer configuration.

Comment: I added more info. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Your edit does not have enough detail. I do not know how NEGs are handled for the lowest latency routing. Hopefully, someone will comment or answer.

Comment: There's not much details about negs in the config. Each neg has a name, region and a cloud run service, that's all.

Comment: The fastest fiber route is not (always) the closest on the globe!

Comment: So, what do you guys suggest if I want middle east users to go to doha region? without using a url map that will require url changes in my apps?

Comment: I do not think there is anything that you can do. I am also wondering if the current problems in the Middle East are affecting network routing temporarily. Do you have specific technical/legal/political reasons for ensuring traffic goes to Doha? You can measure network latency and performance to Doha and compare it with South Carolina.

Comment: The reason I want traffic to go to Doha is to reduce latency. By having both the db and server in middle east, users will get faster responses. Currenrly they experience slowness due the server+db being far away from them in a different continent.

Comment: What are the results of your measurements for both regions? Put those details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The traffic should send the request to the closest region when multiple regions are used, but here in your case it is directed to the other closest region. This might be due to the region reaching the capacity or the backend is unhealthy and traffic overflowing to another closest region.

The [external Application Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/about-capacity-optimization-with-global-lb#how_https_load_balancing_works) uses a special load balancing algorithm called **Waterfall by Region**.This algorithm determines the optimal backend for servicing the request by taking into account the proximity of the instances to the users, the incoming load as well as the available capacity of backends in each zone and region. Finally, worldwide load and capacity is also taken into account. The external Application Load Balancer distributes traffic based on available instances.

**Traffic overflow to other regions**

If an entire region reaches capacity as determined by the [serving capacity set in the backend services](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service), the algorithm is triggered, and traffic overflows to the closest region that has available capacity. As each region reaches capacity, traffic spills to the next closest region, and so on. A region's proximity to the user is defined by network round-trip time from the GFE to the instance backends.

**Cross-regional overflow due to unhealthy backends**

If health checks discover that more than half of the backends in a region are unhealthy, the GFEs preemptively overflow some traffic to the next closest region. This happens in order to avoid traffic completely failing as the region becomes unhealthy. This overflow occurs even if the remaining capacity in the region with the unhealthy backends is sufficient.

Also there are some limitations associated with configuring internet NEGs as backends. Connections to internet NEG endpoints use the internet while keeping your traffic on Google's high performance backbone for the longest possible distance, for reduced latency and improved throughput. Please refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts#limitations) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Though all targets are healthy. When I removed the us-east1 backend from the backend service, requests went to doha region without issues. Also, I forgot to mention that I use a serverless neg with cloud run. If you think my issue could be caused by some limitations of neg, then how do you suggest I connect the load balancer to cloud run?